# how to setcookie in right path?

Tags: php

classlogin.php

```
/*set cookies*/
            $cookie_name = 'check[user]';
            $cookie_value = 'check[authID]';

            // start set cookie //
            //** cookie need to change right away after user press login**//
            setcookie($cookie_name,$value,time()+(60*60*24),'','','',TRUE);
            setcookie($cookie_value,$valueID,time()+(60*60*24),'','','',TRUE);
```

index.php

```
<?php
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

my folder root.

```
root

-->class-->classlogin.php(set cookie here>


-->directory-->index.php(check cookie here>
```

my intetion is to set cookie at classlogin.php , i checked $_COOKIE at classlogin.php , it exits.

but when i try to access cookie at index.php , it was empty, i search online it said my cookie need to have a domain name ? so i can access there. but i tried many domain noting work.

can anyone help me ? how i set my cookie in right path ? i am using wamp localhost.

Comment: you're not setting a path. you have `''` - empty path. and you need to explain HOW your classlogin is executed. I doubt you're directly hitting that file via `http://example.com/class/classlogin.php`. you need to say WHERE that file is being included from.

Comment: _Parameter 4:_ The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in. **A direct quote from the manual... of all the strange places to look for information Eh**

Comment: i got it ~ thank you ~